# How to create self-closing tag in Jsoup?

Tags: java, tags, jsoup

How to create self-closing tag in Jsoup?

Tag.valueOf("tag") creates `<tag></tag>` , but I need `<tag/>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the HTML setter methods in Element Element.html(String html) or Element.prepend(String html) or Element.append(String html).

[more info](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/modifying-data/set-html)

Example:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

public class JsoupTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       String html = "<html><head><title>someTitle</title></head>"
                    + "<body><div><p></P></div></body></html>";
       Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
       doc.body().select("div").first().prepend("<my-tag/>");
       System.out.println(doc.toString());
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure You can create a self closing tag using jsoup. But you can create your own tag using  Java

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       String tagname = Tag.valueOf("ol").getName();
        createSelfClosedTag(tagname);


    }

    public static String createSelfClosedTag(String tagName){
        StringBuilder selfTagBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        if (tagName!=null){
           selfTagBuilder.append("<").append(tagName).append("/>");
        }
        return selfTagBuilder.toString();
    }


}
```

Output:

```
<ol/>
```